# Petclinic hibernate.dialect for HSQL

Tags: spring, hibernate, hsqldb

I am trying to understand Spring Petclinic Application.

By default it seems that HSQL database and JPA is used, but I am unableto to find where the Hibernate Dialect for HSQL is mentioned in the application. 
I understand that it is a mandatory property for Hibernate.

Kindly suggest

Answer (score 0):

What about where `org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect` and where the driver is `org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver`. Normally, if this is a Spring application, this will be present in an `applicationContext.xml` or `tx-datasource.xml` configuration file. Whatever is the case, these properties must be in one of the XML Spring configuration files. Of course, they may be in a Java class (an alternative), but in most applications, they are present in Spring XML files where the `dataSource` bean is defined. Usually, in web applications, that would be in directory under `/WEB-INF` or `/webapp/WEB-INF`.

Comment: Yes this is the hibernate dialect for HSQL .But I am unable to find this mentioned in Petclinic application . Checked the data-access.properties file of petclinic application

Comment: Yep, I have added to my comment.

Comment: The only configuration present for HSQL is

Comment: # HSQL Settings

jdbc.driverClassName=org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver
jdbc.url=jdbc:hsqldb:mem:petclinic
jdbc.username=sa
jdbc.password=

# Properties that control the population of schema and data for a new data source
jdbc.initLocation=classpath:db/hsqldb/initDB.sql
jdbc.dataLocation=classpath:db/hsqldb/populateDB.sql

# Property that determines which database to use with an AbstractJpaVendorAdapter
jpa.database=HSQL

jpa.showSql=true

Comment: Just for more information , I have downloaded the petclinic applicatio n from Github i.e git clone https://github.com/SpringSource/spring-petclinic.git

Comment: It seems that because of spring's extensive up port of HSQL it does not need to define the dialect. http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/jdbc.html#jdbc-embedded-database-support